# Задать больше одного значения в поле объекта java

Tags: java, объекты

Добрый день. Прошу подсказать (не реализовать) каким образом, я могу добавлять больше одного значения в поле объекта. Допустим, есть класс Стол, и у него поле - крепежный материал. А вот крепежный материал, в разных столах может быть разным, могут быть и шурупы и болты. Как мне сразу два и более значений добавить ?

Comment: Использовать список или массив.

Comment: То есть использовать коллекцию, как поле класса ?

Comment: Да, если вы хотите одному столу задать и шурупы и болты. А если у вас будет много столов и у каждого будут либо шурупы, либо болты, то все по-другому. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: @NIkolay Barda Может лучше пересмотреть дизайн с самого начала? К примеру сделать отдельный класс "КрепежныйМатериал" и наследоваться от него. Или например сделать интерфейс. Имплементимся от этого интерфейса и реализовываем методы. Разным столам, разные крепежные материалы.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja Уточняю вопрос. будут создаваться столы, у одних будут и болты и шурупы и иные креп. материалы у других будут только болты или только шурупы.